# opencart set session maxlifetime

Tags: php, session, opencart

i am trying to set a specific time for session lifetime in opencart,

digging into OpenCart structure i found the file session handler `system/library/session.php`

```
<?php
class Session {
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {     
        if (!session_id()) {
            ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');

            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
            session_start();
        }

        $this->data =& $_SESSION;
    }

    function getId() {
        return session_id();
    }
}
?>
```

i am doing some tests to view if what i'm doing is ok, then i created a my_sessions in `system` folder and edited the timings to let die sessions after one minute:

```
<?php
class Session {
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {     
        if (!session_id()) {
            ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');

            session_set_cookie_params(60, '/');
            ini_set('session.cache_expire', '1');
            ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '60');
            ini_set('session.save_path',DIR_SYSTEM.'my_sessions');

            session_start();
        }

        $this->data =& $_SESSION;
    }

    function getId() {
        return session_id();
    }
}
?>
```

Now i can see session files inside the folder, but they seem to live as long as before any modifications.
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `session.gc_maxlifetime` says:

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and **POTENTIALLY** cleaned up

It may clean it up or may leave it at the time. Whether to clean in or not depends on `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`. It is not a problem on a site with a lot of visits. But you can observe it on your local machine with a few visits.

Anyway it is better to rely not on server side garbage collector but on a cookies lifetime.

Comment: i tried to `ini_set('session.gc_probability', '100');` but doesn't seem to work.
After a minute session still lives

Comment: i cleaned browser cookies, deleted session files saved in my_sessions folder, then logged in admin panel, waited a minute and few seconds, then clicked on a random link of the page, alsto tried to refresh the page.

Comment: Are you still logged in when you refresh the page?